# Can't run PrimeFaces Extensions java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.util.ComponentTraversalUtils

Tags: primefaces-extensions

Gretting I'm struggling with this exception and I can't find any help.

My jars are

[jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZe8.jpg)

My primefaces config

[primefaces config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmzBv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just need to add all the necessary depended jars of prime-extensions.